# Load changed data in jQuery UI autocomplete in open state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I’m using [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to implement autocomplete widget in my application. What I'm trying to do is, to **load changes in it's source live even in open state** ([autocomplete widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in expanded state).

**For example:**

```
dummyArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'Bazz'];

$('#target').autocomplete({
  source: dummyArray;
});
```

**After few seconds changed to:**

```
dummyArray = ['loading..'];
$('#target').autocomplete('option', 'source', dummyArray);
```

**and after few mini-seconds it'll be:**

```
dummyArray = ['something', 'goes', 'here'];
$('#target').autocomplete('option', 'source', dummyArray);
```

It's work fine when i collapse/close autocomplete and expand/open it again. But not in open state, that's why some time it shows text/data which is not relevant anymore.

Comment: check the function, where the source data is changed.. there, call the `autocomplete` plugin again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `search` method is for: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

```
dummyArray = ['something', 'goes', 'here'];
$('#target').autocomplete('option', 'source', dummyArray);
$('#target').autocomplete('search');
```

Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2eL26jL7/1/

Comment: Is there any method that returns state(is it open or closed) of autocomplete widget?

Comment: Not on the widget itself. You can use `.autocomplete("widget")` to get the underlying menu element, then use the standard mechanism to check if it's visible eg. `$('#target').autocomplete('widget').is(':visible')`